# I've used the same syntax in other child component,but this eroor doesn't show up there. Anyone suggestions to how to fix this?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZxc5.png)

[this is the code that shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbkEI.png)
the variable is holding the data, i think syntax is correct. I don't know how to fix this.

I want the details to show in the form of the a table.
Same pattern gives the output in other child component,but this component shows this error.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: The error you get happens because the module in which you declare your component isn't importing `CommonModule` (which is where the `*ngFor` directive is exported from).

Comment: it is imported in the app.module.ts

Comment: Have you imported FormsModule in the module ( ie.., module at which you declared your child component)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whether you had added BrowserModule in import of main app module

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).